# How to clear variable content in powershell

Tags: powershell

I just started yesterday learning about powershell. Very new into powershell. I have created quite a few variables for testing purposes. Below is my questions on variables

1. How can i list back all the variables that I have created before?
2. How do I then clear all the contents of the variables?
3. How do I remove/delete a variables?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. How can I list back all the variables that I have created before?

   - This gets all the variables, not just the ones you created, you need to filter to variable you are concerned about:  `Get-Variable -name <name without $>`
2. How do I then clear all the contents of the variables?

   - `Clear-Variable -name <name without $>`
3. How do I remove/delete a variable?

   - `Remove-Variable -name <name without $>`

Comment: Thanks Travis. Really helpful info. However, when I use the Get-Variable $myvariable, it displays error " Get-Variable : Cannot find a variable with the name 'variable name' ". The same error msg when I use the Clear-Variable

Comment: Type the variable name without the $

Comment: Added clarification to the answer for this issue

Comment: how to clean a global variable from inside a function?